# How to select specific data from CSV files and display all the data in that row

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a code that shows all the details of specific students. The code takes an input of gender and their class and then shows all their data. For example, if I input "Male" and "10A", I want the code to give me all the data from the students who are male and in class 10A. All their information is stored in a CSV file (called details). My code so far is:

```
file = open("details.csv","rt")
gender_input = input("Input gender of students")
class_input = input("Input class of students")
for line in file:
    details_of_gender = line.split(",")
    details_of_class = line.split(",")
    gender = str(details_of_gender[7])
    class1 = str(details_of_class[8])
    if gender == "Male":
        if class1 == "10A":
            print(details[0] + " " + details[1] + " " + details[2] + " " + details[3] + " " + details[4] + " " + details[5])
        if class1 == "10B":
            print(details[0] + " " + details[1] + " " + details[2] + " " + details[3] + " " + details[4] + " " + details[5])
    if gender == "Female":
        if class1 == "10A":
            print(details[0] + " " + details[1] + " " + details[2] + " " + details[3] + " " + details[4] + " " + details[5])
        if class1 == "10B":
            print(details[0] + " " + details[1] + " " + details[2] + " " + details[3] + " " + details[4] + " " + details[5])
```

Comment: What is your question? You should take a look into the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and into the [`.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Comment: Give the sample of your csv file row data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your program isn't working just because you're using a variable `details` that you haven't defined before, here's a better way of doing this:

```
import csv
with open("details.csv", newline="") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)                  # use the csv module to read a CSV file!
    for row in reader:
        gender = row[7]
        class = row[8]
        if gender in ("Male", "Female") and class in ("10A", "10B"):
            print(" ".join(row[:6]))             # join elements 0-5 with spaces
```